# How to make a loop continue to next entry when encountering RuntimeError

Tags: python, for-loop, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, data-fitting

I am trying to fit several sets of data using optimize.curve_fit, going over them in a for loop.
Sometimes the fitting fails and I get the error message

> RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded.

Which stops the entire code.
I want the code to be able to skip to the next round of the loop once encountering this error instead of stopping altogether, so that I can go over all of my datasets, but I don't know how to do that.

I would also appreciate an advice regarding how to fit better and potentially avoid this error.

Comment: You should use a `try...except` statement to handle the error. If you need more help, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you'll need to use exception handling in your code. A simple example follows. An infinite loop that prompts for input, converts it to an int and adds `1` to that int. A `ValueError` exception will be raised if the input cannot be converted to an int.

```
while True:

  try:
    i = int(input())
  except ValueError:
    continue

  print(1 + i)
```

In the above the exception is handled by skipping directly to the next iteration of the loop with `continue`.